# How to create a Carousel Page in Xamarin Forms using Fresh MVVM?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I want to create a carousel page in my Xamarin Forms App using Fresh MVVM, the problem is that FreshMVVM does not offer a class to create a carousel page like it does with FreshNavigationContainer or with FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer, so I cant bind the page with the view model nor I can call it from my navigation stacks.

I have found two or three posts about this matter, but all of them were outdated (from 2016 or 2017) and they did not have a way to implement carousel pages using Fresh MVVM.

With this said, is there any way to implement a carousel page in 2020 or it is still impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `CarouselView` is control available in Xamarin.Forms 4.4, you can use it like any other Xamarin control including in Fresh MVVM.